# In Javascript why do I have to use getElementById instead the id itself to access a DOM element and its properties?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

Suppose I have the following html DOM element:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="theckboxid" checked="true" />
```

I know that in Javascript I can access to the `checked` property (or any other property of the element) by using a bunch of ways. I'll focus on the following two ways:

```
var isChkd = document.getElementById('theckboxid').checked;
```

or just

```
var isChkd = theckboxid.checked;
```

In both cases the result will be that into the variable `isChkd` will be stored the Boolean value `true`.
Even using the consolle in Chrome I get exactly the same result.

So the questions are:

Why is better to use `getElementById` instead the direct use of the id to access the element and its properties?

What are pro and cons of both approaches?

Comment: [Because.](https://jsfiddle.net/88ungw5f/)

Comment: They are not implemented by all browsers and IDs could be invalid variable names like `id="this-is-a-valid-id"`!

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks for the immediate response. Sorry not clear: let me better understand: you have kind of redefined as variable the id of the chkbx? Why do I have to do a thing like that?

Comment: I showed you an example of how trying to use the element ID directly as if it is a variable could break, i.e., if an actual variable happens to be defined with the same name. Read the answers in the linked question.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Thanks for the response. Please explicate better "They are not implemented by all browsers". Also I didn't used "this-is-a-valid-id" as var name neither as id... Infact the id I used "theckboxid" is perfectly valid for both uses.

Comment: The point is using the element ID directly only works *sometimes*. Using `.getElementById()` works all the time.